# Reference Loop Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to include a parent object for GET API call since we are following a code-first approach and generic repository pattern so for each entity we have a separate repository and service.

So we have an `IQueryable` object inside repository where we include child collection or parent object

```
public class GenUnLocationRepository : EFRepository<GenUnLocation, string>, IGenUnLocationRepository
{
        public GenUnLocationRepository(RequestScope<InspectionEfContext> requestScope)
            : base(requestScope)
        {
        }

        public override IQueryable<GenUnLocation> Query => base.Query.Include(x=>x.Zipcode);
}
```

So when I am querying the database I get this result

```
"1": {
        "id": "1",
        "fullname": "JPN",
        "shortName": "JP",
        "stateCode": null,
        "longitude": 139.7514,
        "latitude": 35.685,
        "stateId": null,
        "state": null,
        "zipcodeId": 3545,
        "zipcode": {
            "id": 3545,
            "zipcode": "4000",
            "genCountry": [],
            "genStates": [],
            "genUnLocation": [
                {
                    "id": "10",
                    "fullname": "BGD",
                    "shortName": "BD",
                    "stateCode": null,
                    "longitude": 90.4086,
                    "latitude": 23.7231,
                    "stateId": null,
                    "state": null,
                    "zipcodeId": 3545,
                    "companyId": "Test Company",
                    "createUserId": null,
                    "createTime": null,
                    "editUserId": null,
                    "editTime": null,
                    "recordStatus": 0,
                    "importId": null,
                    "baseApplicationId": 0,
                    "baseClientId": 0,
                    "baseClientSupplierId": 0,
                    "baseSupplierId": 0,
                    "baseCode": "Test BaseCode",
                    "baseCode2": "Test BaseCode2",
                    "baseFixedRefCode": "Test BaseFixedRefCode",
                    "baseName": "Test Base Name",
                    "baseDescription": "Test Base Description",
                    "baseStatusId": 0,
                    "baseTypeId": 0,
                    "baseCompanyHierarchyId": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": "100",
                    "fullname": "PRK",
                    "shortName": "KP",
                    "stateCode": null,
                    "longitude": 125.7547,
                    "latitude": 39.0194,
                    "stateId": null,
                    "state": null,
                    "zipcodeId": 3545,
                    "companyId": "Test Company",
                    "createUserId": null,
                    "createTime": null,
                    "editUserId": null,
                    "editTime": null,
                    "recordStatus": 0,
                    "importId": null,
                    "baseApplicationId": 0,
                    "baseClientId": 0,
                    "baseClientSupplierId": 0,
                    "baseSupplierId": 0,
                    "baseCode": "Test BaseCode",
                    "baseCode2": "Test BaseCode2",
                    "baseFixedRefCode": "Test BaseFixedRefCode",
                    "baseName": "Test Base Name",
                    "baseDescription": "Test Base Description",
                    "baseStatusId": 0,
                    "baseTypeId": 0,
                    "baseCompanyHierarchyId": 0
                },
}
```

As you can see I am querying `GenUnlocation` and including `GenZipCode` but inside `Zipcode` we obviously would have an `ICollection` object of `GenUnlocation` which is the child of `GenZipCode` entity.

Can not figure out why its filling `ICollection` object and how should I stop or control it

JSON serializer settings in `Startup` class are :

```
 services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

            if (Environment.IsProduction())
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As usual: relationship fixup.

Comment: Are you sure you want completely different serialization semantics in your production environment? That's a recipe for bugs if ever I've seen one